# Configure HostName on Ubuntu Server

Tags: networking, server, ssh, git, gitlab

then I'm using an ubuntu server with gitlab installed, I need to configure hostname the name ubuntudev, to access it from within the network! I configure the ubuntudev name in /etc/hosts but it does not work with the hostname, how can I fix this error? I put under the contents of the /etc/hosts file

**--> /etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       ubuntudev

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: if you try the command `ping ubuntudev` you'll be pinging 127.0.1.1 so you'll likely find what you did worked, it just didn't do what you intended.  `/etc/hosts` preceeded the dhcp protocol (ie. arpanet days) and is only a list of ip-addresses and names to access those ip.addresses.  I think what you wanted to change was `/etc/hostname`

Comment: @guiverc I have already added what you also say that, but still do not go

Comment: changing the file does nothing until you reboot, or restart the required.....  (the file is only read during init type processes then is accessed from memory -- you have to force re-read)  note: I don't use gitlab, so do not know it significance to your issues..

Comment: @guiverc does not respond to ping

Comment: @guiverc I've already tried to rewind it, but the result is the same!

Comment: Which server is your DNS nameserver in this network? Is it the same server which's hostname you are changing?

Comment: yes it's same..

Comment: @guiverc reboot is not required, you can set a hostname with `hostname` but. IMHO, `hostnamectl` is preferred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you set a new hostname with

```
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname new_hostname
```

You can also do so by editing BOTH `/etc/hostname` and /etc/hosts` . Direct editing is discouraged because if you do not edit both you can break sudo.

> panther@Ubuntu:~$hostname Ubuntu 
>   panther@Ubuntu:~$sudo hostnamectl set-hostname it_works
>
> panther@Ubuntu:~$**hostname**
>
> **it_works**
>
> panther@Ubuntu:~$ping -c1 it_works
>
> PING it_works (10.0.0.8) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from it_works
>   (10.0.0.8): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.020 ms
>
> --- it_works ping statistics --- 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.020/0.020/0.020/0.000 ms
>
> panther@Ubuntu:~$sudo hostnamectl set-hostname Ubuntu
>
> panther@Ubuntu:~$**hostname**
>
> **Ubuntu**

Comment: It’s not works....

Comment: If you need help, update your question with the commands you ran and any error messages you get. Both methods works to set hostname.

Comment: set-hostname doesnt affect the hosts file. (ubuntu 18.04) you need to edit that manually after you run the update command.